# TYPO3 - Flexforms displayCond

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements

I need help with the TYPO3 Flexforms and this displayCond!

`<displayCond>FIELD:settings.slider.slides.slider.layout:=:default</displayCond>`

this Example dont work too:
`<displayCond>FIELD:settings.slider.slides.layout:=:default</displayCond>`

it dont work in the array :(
here a flexform example

```
<slider>
        <ROOT>
            <TCEforms>
                <sheetTitle>Slider</sheetTitle>                                     
          <displayCond>FIELD:sDEF.switchableControllerActions:=:Elements->slider</displayCond>
            </TCEforms>
            <type>array</type>
            <el>
                <settings.slider.slides type="array">
                    <title>only first 3 items are used</title>
                    <type>array</type>
                    <section>1</section>
                    <el>
                        <slider>
                            <type>array</type>
                            <title>Slide</title>
                            <el>

                                <!-- Slider Settings
                                ====================================================================== -->
                                <layout>
                                    <TCEforms>
                                        <label>Layout</label>
                                        <onChange>reload</onChange>
                                        <config>
                                            <type>select</type>
                                            <items>
                                                <numIndex index="10">
                                                    <numIndex index="0">Default</numIndex>
                                                    <numIndex index="1">default</numIndex>
                                                </numIndex>
                                                <numIndex index="20">
                                                    <numIndex index="0">Landingpage</numIndex>
                                                    <numIndex index="1">landingpage</numIndex>
                                                </numIndex>
                                            </items>
                                        </config>
                                    </TCEforms>
                                </layout>


                                <image>
                                    <TCEforms>
                                        <label>Image</label>
                                        <displayCond>FIELD:settings.slider.slides.slider.layout:=:default</displayCond>
                                        <config>
                                            <type>group</type>
                                            <internal_type>file</internal_type>
                                            <allowed>jpg, jpeg, gif, png</allowed>
                                            <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
                                            <minitems>0</minitems>
                                            <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                            <size>1</size>
                                        </config>
                                    </TCEforms>
                                </image>
```

Comment: try to use `<displayCond>FIELD:layout:=:default</displayCond>`.

Comment: jep, i found the Problem ;) see my Answer :) thanks!

Comment: ```<displayCond>FIELD:layout:=:default</displayCond>```
This will work only if have layout default, but i wanted to show this field if my layout is col2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<displayCond>FIELD:layout:=:default</displayCond>
```

this works fine ;)
I am in the right settings... "settings.slider.slides...."
And now I need only the first array: "layout"

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the below **displayCond**:

```
<displayCond>FIELD:layout:=:default</displayCond>
```